# Showing days, weeks or months since a given date

Tags: dates

I'm writing a mobile app, in which users can record a date for something that happened in the past. On the main screen, they can see the date they saved, and next to it, the number of days since this date.

It looks like this:
[image: 6days]

This is fine, but if the number of days becomes larger, the elapsed time becomes less clear:
[image: 118days]

I can have access to:

- the number of days since the date recorded (406)
- the number of weeks & days since the date recorded (16 & 6)
- the number of months, weeks & days since the date recorded (3, 3 & 5)

It's fairly easy to imagine switching to the upper unit when it's non-null. For example, 0-6 days, 1-4 weeks, 1-12 months. The issue with this basic approach is that 1 month and 26 days would show up as "1 month" when it's closer to 2.

I could combine 2 units (weeks & days, months & weeks, etc.) but I don't really like this option, given the space it requires (it's a mobile app so I'd like to keep it short).

I understand there's no "rule" regarding this, but how would you handle such a situation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Week is a bit tricky here. Also month counting is not consistent with month length between 28 and 31 days (average 30.4).

But you need some human-readable numbers here. Provided you are not opting for rounding, what about the following schema?

- less than **8 days** -> display the number of **days**

  > 4 days => **4 days**
- less than **1 month** -> display the number of **weeks** and **days**

  > 20 days => **2 weeks** and **6 days**
- less than **1 year** -> display the number of **months** and **days** (if the remaining days **not** divisible by 7)

  > 42 days => **1 month** and **12 days**
- less than **1 year** -> display the number of **months** and **weeks** (if the remaining days divisible by 7)

  > 44 days => **1 month** and **2 weeks**
- more than **1 year** -> display the number of **years** and perform the above schema with the **remainder of the days**

  > 400 days => **1 year**, **1 month** and **5 days**
- more than **1 year** -> if the remainder of months is a quarter, display the number of **years** and perform the above schema for less than a month with the **remainder of the days**

  > 470 days => **1¼ years** and **15 days**

However the latest is not that clear, in my opinion.

Bottom line - use no more than two units at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a potential solution I talk about in my post, where I state that it may end up taking too much space. Nevertheless, I also think it's the only comprehensible option available.

Comment: @rdurand, if lack of space is your problem try either abbreviations like "d" for days, "w" for weeks, "m" for months, etc. or rotate the unit counterclockwise by 90 degrees.

Comment: rotating the units is interesting (although maybe painful to code, but that's another subject), thanks ! :)

Comment: @rdurand - if it is Android, wouldn't [Canvas.drawTextOnPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath) be a solution for you?

Comment: probably, but it's iOS :)

Comment: Agreed; I generally cap it to the two largest units, and provide an accurate timestamp in a tooltip (not applicable here though). But it really depends on the use case.

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention a requirement for precision. If exactly *when* the thing was recorded isn't as important as about how long ago you could do something like:

> **4 Days**

and then (although not accounting for February, leap years etc:

35 days would be (Imagining as a round)

> **About 1 Month**

80 Days

> **About 3 Months**

And for 360 Days:

> **About 1 Year**

If you want a little more precision without it being critical, you could leave the decimal places to 1 digit:

196 days:

> **About 6.4 Months**

And it's always possible to add the functionality to click the control and get more details such as the exact date or time span.

Comment: Thank you for your insights on this. Although it wasn't mentioned, I think in this case using "about" would cause more confusion than anything. I also ruled out the decimal option as the values (weeks, months) are not base ten, which makes the decimals sometimes unclear for the user. But now that I'm thinking about it, using only .5 decimals could improve the precision while keeping the readability (on can figure 3.5 months easily). With this comes the issue @Mike noted that months can be 28-31 days and 4-5 weeks.

Comment: @rdurand I agree 100%, you could easily get away with just the easy round decimals. Also, I did consider the 28-31 days problem, and ~1 month is even fuzzy for people. Jan 30 - Feb 28th is "1 month" by most counts, but so would be Feb 28th to March 28th OR March 31st to most people who aren't worried about say accounting or edge cases. In a comment system for example I doubt 99% of your users would notice the lack of precision PLUS you'd have the disclaimer of "about". *End of explaining how this could theoretically work, even if not for you*

Answer (score 2):

Visually it would be superior to simply display the number of days. The key question that must be answered is " What is the usefulness of this information?" and secondly "How will this information influence the action of the user?"

Assuming the user will not act differently if he sees 89 days or 91 days then simply listing the days ought to be fine. If he knows he must do "x" every quarter then more information is needed.

However there comes a point where listing the number of days becomes silly: example 1723 and certainly something  like 11,234 days.

Based upon the information given I would display 1-365 days and then go to "More than 1 Year", "More than 2 Years", etc...